# react suite (rsuite) package installation is failing

Tags: reactjs, npm, failed-installation, rsuite

When I tried to install rsuite (version 4.9.3) package using the command,

```
npm i rsuite
```

I am getting this error. Can anyone help me with this installation process?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/mini-create-react-context
npm ERR!     mini-create-react-context@"^0.4.0" from react-router@5.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-router
npm ERR!       react-router@"5.2.0" from react-router-dom@5.2.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-router-dom
npm ERR!         react-router-dom@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   6 more (react-dom, react-router, react-router-dom, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha" from react-virtualized@9.22.3
npm ERR! node_modules/rsuite/node_modules/react-virtualized
npm ERR!   react-virtualized@"^9.21.0" from rsuite@4.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/rsuite
npm ERR!     rsuite@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/mikhil/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mikhil/.npm/_logs/2021-03-22T06_42_23_555Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You try the following command

```
npm install --force
```

or

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```